# Encrypting/signing with libsodium to myself?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, libsodium

I've got a list of public keys, and my private key, and want to provide a signed/encrypted data value for all of them, including myself.

Is it safe to sign/encrypt to myself as to all others? In `crypt_box_easy` (with  a random nonce which gets published), can I use the private/public keys from a single keypair?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for sure you can. In PGP it is even semi-standard for you to encrypt for yourself as well. Using your own public key doesn't leak any information about the message or private key. This reasoning is not so libsodium specific, it's likely to be valid for any PKI based protocol.

The signature generation is of course exactly identical, nothing needs to change there. It has the added benefit that you can (hopefully) trust any public key for which you manage the private key. There's no difference there.

Beware that it is generally better to use separate key pairs for encryption and signing. Please make sure that libsodium matches your needs in that regard. Key management is always the tricky part of applications that use cryptography.

Comment: Thanks. I'm mostly asking because using plain RSA with both parts of a keypair leaks the plaintext; now `libsodium` used eg. ED25519 and mixes a nonce in, but that doesn't automatically mean that using both parts of a single keypair becomes valid!

Comment: Yeah,  true but plain RSA should not be used in the first place. Libsodium had been designed to be used with one key pair per entity, so risks are smaller in that sense.